# Custom metric written in Cython for NearestNeighbors is still slow

Tags: python, numpy, cython

As described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287236/why-is-knn-slow-with-custom-metric), KNN is pretty slow with custom metric written in pure python. I rolled out my own custom metric written in Cython, but it is still very slow.

Here is my custom metric written in Cython `distances.pyx`. It is pretty straightforward as it computes Euclidean distance for the first 3 dimensions and Chordal distance for the rest dimension. `src` and `dst` here have a shape of all `12x1`.

```
import numpy
cimport numpy
from libc.math cimport sqrt


def euclidean_chordal(numpy.ndarray[numpy.float_t, ndim=1] src, dst):
    cdef int i
    cdef int dims = src.shape[0]
    cdef double diff
    cdef double euclidean_loss = 0.0
    cdef double chordal_loss = 0.0
    # Euclidean distance for point clouds and Chordal distance for frames
    for i in range(dims):
        diff = src[i] - dst[i]
        if i < 3:
            euclidean_loss += diff * diff
        else:
            chordal_loss += diff * diff
    euclidean_loss = sqrt(euclidean_loss)
    chordal_loss = sqrt(chordal_loss)

    return euclidean_loss + chordal_loss
```

And here is the `setup.py`

```
# Run python setup.py build_ext --inplace

from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

import numpy


setup(ext_modules=cythonize("distances.pyx"), include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])
```

Then I tested the `euclidean_chordal` with `sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors`. It is still extremely slow. Does anyone know what is happening here?

```
from distance.distances import euclidean_chordal
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

# src here is a point cloud with a shape of 76800 x 12
# dst here is a point cloud with a shape of 76800 x 12
neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, metric=lambda a, b: euclidean_chordal(a, b))
neigh.fit(dst)
distances, indices = neigh.kneighbors(src, return_distance=True)
```

Comment: Can you include the result of `neigh.effective_metric_params_` ?

Comment: In any case, your best bet is to add `algorithm = 'ball_tree'` into your `neigh` definition, since it's likely falling back to brute force and `kd_tree` (which is the really fast algorithm) isn't possible with user-defined metrics.  If `ball_tree` isn't fast enough, you'll be stuck trying to implement a KDTree algorithm for your metric and  . . . well I hope you like Lie Algebra.

Comment: All that assumes your `cython` is working right.  I have nothing to add there.

Comment: `dst` isn't typed